# File in Use etc

Tags: c#, xslt

We have a custom app that writes stats to an XML file every 10 seconds.
A web service reads in the XML and does a transform on it every 3 seconds. About every 5 refreshes (arbitrary number) we get a blank screen b/c the web service is trying to read from the file while we are writing to the file.

I cannot do anything about the webservice or how it reads in the file. What I need to do be able to write to the file w/o causing the page to blank out.

Any ideas?

This is C# btw .NET 4

Comment: For the record we will be changing how all this works in our next release. Instead of using a file based system I will re-write this as a RESTful service which the XSL will then query. This will remove this problem for good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code to write to a different filename, then call `File.Replace()` to atomically swap out the original file.

This way, you want lock the file for any noticeable amount of time.

Comment: This worked, we had tried File.Move() and File.Copy() to no avail previously, didnt even consider trying this until you suggested it.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the filename that you are writing to a different one (adding a timestamp after the filename can be a good practice), so it won't get locked. Then you can replace the old file with the new file that you've just created.